# Camera preview stretched even after setting the correct dimensions

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I'm creating a camera app that implements it's own camera preview for taking pictures.
The app is currently forced into portrait mode.

My problem is that the preview from the camera is slightly stretched (the aspect ratio is a bit off).
The funny thing is that I'm setting my SurfaceView size to always match the preview size. This ensures that the aspect ratio should always be perserved... but it isn't...

Here is the layout i use to show my camera preview:

```
public class Cp extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private final String TAG = "CameraPreview";

    private boolean mPreviewRunning = false;

    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Size mPreviewSize;
    private List<Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public boolean IsPreviewRunning() {
        return mPreviewRunning;
    }

    public Cp(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public Cp(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public Cp(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        addView(mSurfaceView);

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        mCamera = camera;
        if (mCamera != null) {
            requestLayout();
        }
    }

    public void switchCamera(Camera camera) {
        setCamera(camera);
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
        }
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        requestLayout();

        camera.setParameters(parameters);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // We purposely disregard child measurements because act as a wrapper to
        // a SurfaceView that
        // centers the camera preview instead of stretching it.
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(),
                widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(),
                heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes == null && mCamera != null) {
            mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters()
                    .getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        }
        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width,
                    height);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        if (changed && getChildCount() > 0) {
            final View child = getChildAt(0);

            final int width = r - l;
            final int height = b - t;

            int previewWidth = width;
            int previewHeight = height;
            if (mPreviewSize != null) {
                previewWidth = mPreviewSize.height;
                previewHeight = mPreviewSize.width;
            }
            if (previewWidth == 0) {
                previewWidth = 1;
            }
            if (previewHeight == 0) {
                previewHeight = 1;
            }

            // Center the child SurfaceView within the parent.
            if (width * previewHeight > height * previewWidth) {
                final int scaledChildWidth = previewWidth * height
                        / previewHeight;
                child.layout((width - scaledChildWidth) / 2, 0,
                        (width + scaledChildWidth) / 2, height);
            } else {
                final int scaledChildHeight = previewHeight * width
                        / previewWidth;
                child.layout(0, (height - scaledChildHeight) / 2, width,
                        (height + scaledChildHeight) / 2);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where to
        // draw.
        try {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
                mSupportedPreviewSizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
        stop();
    }

    private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
        if (sizes == null)
            return null;

        Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
        for (Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
                continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and
            // begin the preview.
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            if (mPreviewSize != null) {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width,
                        mPreviewSize.height);
            }
            requestLayout();

            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            mPreviewRunning = true;
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mPreviewRunning = false;
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that in `onLayout` width and height are swapped because the app is always running in portrait.

I'm including some pictures to show you what the problem looks like:
[image]

[image]

I've debugged the code. The preview size is being set to 1280x720 and the size of the layout is also being correctly adjusted to match that size.

I've also tried different layouts but the result was always the same...

Comment: related: [*Camera Preview Stretched on Few Android Devices*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049293/camera-preview-stretched-on-few-android-devices)

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem, after some days in this puzzle, my Java class end up on this code:

So, The problem was happening because the camera display had a size (hight x width) 576x720, and my display was 1184x720. So, the camera preview (my surface view class) stretched to fill in the parent.

So, the approach that worked is to make this view bigger than my screen, and that just display the area of my screen. So, I had to use this weird frame combination (a relative layout inside a linearlayout), so that the size of the relative will be as big as I want - the surface view will fill in it -, and the linear will take just the part that I wanna display.

```
package com.example.frame.camera;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.frame.MainActivity;

public class NativeCamera extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    static private NativeCamera instance;

    private LinearLayout        frame               = null;
    private RelativeLayout      innerFrame          = null;

    private Camera              camera;
    private final SurfaceHolder previewHolder;
    private static final String TAG                 = "NativeCamera.java";

    private boolean             inPreview           = false;
    private boolean             cameraConfigured    = false;
    private boolean             frontCamera         = false;

    private Camera.Size         size;

    static public NativeCamera getInstance() {
        if (NativeCamera.instance == null) {
            if (MainActivity.debug) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Creating Camera Singleton");
            }
            NativeCamera.instance = new NativeCamera(MainActivity.instance);
        }
        return NativeCamera.instance;
    }

    public void onResume() {
        if (MainActivity.debug) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
        }
        camera = Camera.open();
        if (size != null) {
            initPreview(size.width, size.height);
        }
        startPreview();
    }

    public void onPause() {
        if (MainActivity.debug) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
        }
        if (inPreview) {
            camera.stopPreview();
        }
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        inPreview = false;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        if (MainActivity.debug) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        }
        NativeCamera.instance = null;
    }

    public void onSwitch() {
        frontCamera = !frontCamera;
        if (inPreview) {
            camera.stopPreview();
        }
        camera.release();

        int cam = frontCamera ? 1 : 0;

        camera = Camera.open(cam);
        if (size != null) {
            initPreview(size.width, size.height);
        }
        startPreview();
    }

    private NativeCamera(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        previewHolder = getHolder();
        previewHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        // previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        innerFrame = new RelativeLayout(MainActivity.instance);
        innerFrame.addView(this);
        frame = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.instance);
        frame.addView(innerFrame);
    }

    public LinearLayout getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (MainActivity.debug) {
            Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged");
        }
        initPreview(width, height);
        startPreview();
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // no-op -- wait until surfaceChanged()

    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // no-op
    }

    private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height,
            Camera.Parameters parameters) {
        Camera.Size result = null;

        for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
            if (size.width <= width && size.height <= height) {
                if (result == null) {
                    result = size;
                } else {
                    int resultArea = result.width * result.height;
                    int newArea = size.width * size.height;

                    if (newArea > resultArea) {
                        result = size;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        this.size = result;
        return (result);
    }

    private void initPreview(int width, int height) {
        if (camera != null && previewHolder.getSurface() != null) {

            if (!cameraConfigured) {
                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                Camera.Size size = getBestPreviewSize(width, height, parameters);

                if (size != null) {
                    parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
                    camera.setParameters(parameters);
                    cameraConfigured = true;
                    // Setting up correctly the view
                    double ratio = size.height / (double) size.width;
                    LayoutParams params = innerFrame.getLayoutParams();
                    params.height = MainActivity.size.y;
                    params.width = (int) (MainActivity.size.y * ratio);
                    innerFrame.setLayoutParams(params);
                    int deslocationX = (int) (params.width / 2.0 - MainActivity.size.x / 2.0);
                    innerFrame.animate().translationX(-deslocationX);
                }
            }

            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
                camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception in setPreviewDisplay()", t);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.instance, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }

    private void startPreview() {
        if (MainActivity.debug) {
            Log.d(TAG, "startPreview");
        }
        if (cameraConfigured && camera != null) {
            camera.startPreview();
            inPreview = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Haven't tested it fully yet, but this actually seems to work. Nice.

Comment: This solution is not worked for me.please refer my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107208/how-to-make-camera-preview-size-same-as-imageview-size-without-preview-stretch

Comment: getBestPreviewSize() always giving me the smaller size of camera and same problem occur view stretch.

Comment: @Eduardo Reis : i am trying implement camera preview like instagram but camera streatch. Preview is not proper. can you help ? Thanks in advance. waiting for your replay.

Answer (score 2):

I have been trying to solve the same issue... Below code worked for me:

```
private void setMyPreviewSize(int width, int height) {
    // Get the set dimensions
    float newProportion = (float) width / (float) height;

    // Get the width of the screen
    int screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int screenHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    float screenProportion = (float) screenWidth / (float) screenHeight;

    // Get the SurfaceView layout parameters
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = surfaceView.getLayoutParams();
    if (newProportion > screenProportion) {
        lp.width = screenWidth;
        lp.height = (int) ((float) screenWidth / newProportion );
    } else {
        lp.width = (int) (newProportion * (float) screenHeight);
        lp.height = screenHeight;
    }
    // Commit the layout parameters
    surfaceView.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

You can see the thread: [Resizing surface view for aspect ratio change in video display in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491499/resizing-surface-view-for-aspect-ratio-change-in-video-display-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution

surfaceChanged is just to get the best preview size

```
@Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
                Log.e("MYTAG", "surfaceChanged " );

                Camera.Parameters myParameters = camera.getParameters();
                Camera.Size myBestSize = getBestPreviewSize(width, height, myParameters);

                if(myBestSize != null){
                    myParameters.setPreviewSize(myBestSize.width, myBestSize.height);
                    camera.setParameters(myParameters);
                    camera.startPreview();


                }
            }



@Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
       imageReview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

This will set the captured image on imageReview, but you need a method to get the rotation of the bitmap

you need to set imageView scaleType attribute for stretched image issue

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />
```