# Resizing surface view for aspect ratio change in video display in android

Tags: android, video, surfaceview, android-mediacodec

I am working on a video conferencing project. My video display is using surface view. Now during a video call there is a chance of aspect ratio change for the incoming frames. So i have tried the following code for it

```
public void surfaceResize() {

   // WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Point size = new Point();
    int screenWidth = 0;
    //Get the SurfaceView layout parameters

    float aspectRatio = (float) recv_frame_width / recv_frame_height;

    if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) 
    {   
        //Get the width of the screen
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
        screenWidth = size.x;

        //Set the width of the SurfaceView to the width of the screen
        surflp.width = screenWidth;

        //Set the height of the SurfaceView to match the aspect ratio of the video 
        //be sure to cast these as floats otherwise the calculation will likely be 0
        surflp.height = (int) ((1 / aspectRatio) * (float)screenWidth);

        //Commit the layout parameters

    } else {

        size.x = size.y = 0;
        //Get the width of the screen
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);

        int screenHeight = size.y;

        //Set the width of the SurfaceView to the width of the screen
        surflp.height = screenHeight;

        //Set the width of the SurfaceView to match the aspect ratio of the video 
        //be sure to cast these as floats otherwise the calculation will likely be 0
        surflp.width = (int) ( aspectRatio * (float)screenHeight);

        //Commit the layout parameters
        // code to do for Portrait Mode        
    }
    surflp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    surflp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);

    if(myVideoSurfaceView != null) 
        myVideoSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(surflp);  
    System.out.println("Surface resized*****************************************");
}
```

Everything is fine if I call this function at beginning of call. 
My problem is when I call this function in between a call for changing aspect ratio it takes too much time to display the next frame. Sometimes the video gets stuck even.

I tried to destroy and recreate the surface with

```
myVideoSurface.setVisibility(VIEW.GONE);
```

But the surface is not getting created.

I am using Mediacodec for video decode I will get notified when there is a resolution change.

Is there something more I should do for resizing a surfaceView when already video is being played.

Thanks for help.........................

Comment: If your problem is solved, please accept an answer. So you question doesn't show up in the "unanswered" list.

Comment: here is a good [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33670521/2220110)

Answer (score 32):

Hello try with below code:

```
private void setVideoSize() {

            // // Get the dimensions of the video
            int videoWidth = mediaPlayer.getVideoWidth();
            int videoHeight = mediaPlayer.getVideoHeight();
            float videoProportion = (float) videoWidth / (float) videoHeight;

            // Get the width of the screen
            int screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
            int screenHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
            float screenProportion = (float) screenWidth / (float) screenHeight;

            // Get the SurfaceView layout parameters
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = surfaceView.getLayoutParams();
            if (videoProportion > screenProportion) {
                lp.width = screenWidth;
                lp.height = (int) ((float) screenWidth / videoProportion);
            } else {
                lp.width = (int) (videoProportion * (float) screenHeight);
                lp.height = screenHeight;
            }
            // Commit the layout parameters
            surfaceView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks kyogs for the fast response.  But I too do something similar recv_frame_width and recv_frame_height are the current frame height and width. I want to know if there is something else to be done with the surfaceView for this change since the video is being played already.

Comment: from surface view you can get video height and width.

Comment: @ kyogs Ya I know that but without that also I have the new width and height and the aspect ratio. but the problem comes when I try to resize my surfaceView, which takes too much time for it and sometimes the video gets stuck.

Comment: myVideoSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(surflp);  This line is throwing some exception also...

Comment: @fadden can i have a help

Comment: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. This is the exception that i get

Comment: You have to make calls that modify the View from the UI thread.  You can use a Handler to "forward" the call.  See e.g. https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html .

Comment: Thank you fadden for the accurate solution

Comment: You save my day ！

Comment: @Fustigador  pls share how u resolved screen aspect ratio

Comment: Doesn't work on my Android 9 device. Works on Android 6...

Answer (score 4):

[image]
This problem can be solved like this.

Comment: you should type that out for the copy-paste army :P

Comment: @SahithVibudhi and for accessibility