# How to display OpenCV JavaCameraView front camera in mirror image (Android)?

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-camera

I am currently experimenting with the openCV's java example on face detection in android. However, the view created by the camera is not in mirror imaging.I tried setting the `android:screenOrientation` to `reverseLandscape` but it did not work. I would like to try to achieve this, any suggestions?

Code in layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
    android:id="@+id/fd_activity_surface_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape"
    />
```

instantiating

```
private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;
```

on OpenCV loaded

```
mOpenCvCameraView.setCameraIndex(1);
mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
```

onCreate() method

```
mOpenCvCameraView = findViewById(R.id.fd_activity_surface_view);
mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
```

mOpenCvCameraView did not contain a setDisplayOrientation() method and setRotation(180) returned me with a black display.

Comment: Thy to set camera index to [CameraBridgeViewBase .CAMERA_ID_FRONT](https://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/android/CameraBridgeViewBase.html#CAMERA_ID_FRONT).

Comment: @AlexCohn, it still does not produce a mirror image

Comment: Try mOpenCvCameraView.setScaleX(-1)

Comment: You can do it via layout [attribute android:scaleX](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scaleX), too.

Comment: @AlexCohn, setting scaleX returns me a black screen :(

Comment: @AlexCohn : Thanks It worked !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimal change to make the mirror is to add the following code to your **CvCameraViewListener2**:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    Mat rgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    Core.flip(rgba, rgba, 1);
    return rgba;
}
```

This is not the most efficient way, but probably acceptable. On my rather weak test device, this reduces FPS from *7.17* to *7.15*.

Answer (score 0):

for horizontal reverse:

```
Core.flip(rgba, rgba, 1);
```

for vertical reverse:

```
Core.flip(rgba, rgba, -1);
```