# Android camera photo preview is coming inverse

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I am working on Camera related app. I have successfully completed capturing photo and photo preview also. But one issue arised. When I take photo, photo Capture is successful but preview is being inverse. I have tried so many solutions from stack overflow though luck did not favor for me so far.

My Camera Preview class is:

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private Context mContext;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        mCamera = camera;
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            // create the surface and start camera preview
            if (mCamera == null) {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void refreshCamera(Camera camera) {
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }
        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }
        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here
        // start preview with new settings
        setCamera(camera);

        // TODO: don't hardcode cameraId '0' here... figure this out later.
        setCameraDisplayOrientation(mContext, Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, mCamera);

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Context context, int cameraId, Camera camera) {
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        int rotation = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degrees = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degrees = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degrees = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degrees = 270;
                break;
        }

        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);

        int result;
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            // Compensate for the mirror image.
            result = (360 - result) % 360;
        } else {
            // Back-facing camera.
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
        refreshCamera(mCamera);
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        //method to set a camera instance
        mCamera = camera;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // mCamera.release();

    }
}
```

and my PhotoCaputeActivity class is below:

```
public class PhotoCaptureActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "PhotoCaptureActivity";

    //Arraylist for image timer animation
    int[] imageArray = {R.drawable.ic_five_128, R.drawable.ic_four_128,
            R.drawable.ic_three_128, R.drawable.ic_two_128, R.drawable.ic_one_128,
            R.drawable.ic_smiley_128
    };
    int i = 0;
    private final static int DELAY = 1000;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    Thread timerThread;

    // Create variable to handle progress and set it to 0.
    private int progress = 0;

    Bitmap bitmap,photoCaptureBitmap;

    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private PictureCallback mPicture;
    private ImageButton capture, switchCamera;
    private Context myContext;
    private LinearLayout cameraPreview;
    private boolean cameraFront = false;
    private ImageView capturedImageHolder;

    private ProgressBar progressBar_take_photo;
    ImageButton next_button_take_photo;
    ImageButton back_button_take_photo;
    TextView photo_title_text;

    ImageView image_animation;
    private MyPreferences myPreferences;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        setContentView(R.layout.photo_capture_activity);

        //setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        Logger.addLogAdapter(new AndroidLogAdapter());
        myContext = this;
        initialize();
        myPreferences = MyPreferences.getPreferences(this);

        nextButton();
        backButton();
        progressBar();
        nameTextShow();

    }

    private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
        int cameraId = -1;
        // Search for the front facing camera
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                cameraId = i;
                cameraFront = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cameraId;
    }

    private int findBackFacingCamera() {
        int cameraId = -1;
        //Search for the back facing camera
        //get the number of cameras
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        //for every camera check
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                cameraId = i;
                cameraFront = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cameraId;
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (!hasCamera(myContext)) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(myContext, "Sorry, your phone does not have a camera!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            finish();
        }
        if (mCamera == null) {
            //if the front facing camera does not exist
            if (findFrontFacingCamera() < 0) {
                //Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //switchCamera.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            mCamera = Camera.open(findFrontFacingCamera());
            mPicture = getPictureCallback();
            mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
        }else{
            //Visibility
            cameraPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            capturedImageHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            String photoCapturePreview = myPreferences.getVisitorPhoto();
            if(!photoCapturePreview.equals("")) {
                photoCaptureBitmap = decodeToBase64(photoCapturePreview);
            }
            capturedImageHolder.setImageBitmap(photoCaptureBitmap);
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeToBase64(String input) {
        byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
    }

    // Code for initialization
    public void initialize() {
        cameraPreview = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cameraFrame);
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(myContext, mCamera);
        cameraPreview.addView(mPreview);

        capture = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        capture.setOnClickListener(captrureListener);

        //switchCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ChangeCamera);
        //switchCamera.setOnClickListener(switchCameraListener);

        image_animation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.timer_text);
        capturedImageHolder = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.captured_image);

        next_button_take_photo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next_button_take_photo);
        back_button_take_photo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back_button_take_photo);
        progressBar_take_photo = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar_take_photo);
        photo_title_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.photo_title_text);
    }

    //Next Button operation based on mobile number input
    private void nextButton() {
        next_button_take_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                hideKeyboard();

                if (bitmap != null) {
                    Intent newIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ConfirmationActivity.class);
                    startActivity(newIntent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //Back button operation
    private void backButton() {
        back_button_take_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent newIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddressInputActivity.class);
                startActivity(newIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    //Progress bar operation
    private void progressBar() {

        //simpleProgressBar.setMax(100); // 100 maximum value for the progress value
        //simpleProgressBar.setProgress(50); // 50 default progress value for the progress bar

        // Get the Drawable custom_progressbar
        //Drawable draw=res.getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progressbar);
        // set the drawable as progress drawable
        //progressBar.setProgressDrawable(draw);
    }

    //Normal text show
    private void nameTextShow() {
        String vsitorName = myPreferences.getVisitorName();
        photo_title_text.setText(vsitorName + ", please smile for the Camera");
    }

    OnClickListener switchCameraListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //get the number of cameras
            int camerasNumber = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
            if (camerasNumber > 1) {
                //release the old camera instance
                //switch camera, from the front and the back and vice versa

                releaseCamera();
                chooseCamera();
            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(myContext, "Sorry, your phone has only one camera!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    };

    public void chooseCamera() {
        //if the camera preview is the front
        if (cameraFront) {
            int cameraId = findBackFacingCamera();
            if (cameraId >= 0) {
                //open the backFacingCamera
                //set a picture callback
                //refresh the preview

                mCamera = Camera.open(cameraId);
                mPicture = getPictureCallback();
                mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
            }
        } else {
            int cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
            if (cameraId >= 0) {
                //open the backFacingCamera
                //set a picture callback
                //refresh the preview

                mCamera = Camera.open(cameraId);
                mPicture = getPictureCallback();
                mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
            }
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //when on Pause, release camera in order to be used from other applications
        releaseCamera();
    }

    private boolean hasCamera(Context context) {
        //check if the device has camera
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private PictureCallback getPictureCallback() {
        PictureCallback picture = new PictureCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                if (data != null) {
                    //make a new picture file
                    File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    myPreferences.setVisitorPhoto(imageEncoded);

                    if (bitmap == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    try {
                        //write the file
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                        fos.write(data);
                        fos.close();
                        //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(myContext, "Picture saved: " + pictureFile.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        //toast.show();

                        //Method for image view
                        captureImageView();

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }

                    //refresh camera to continue preview
                    mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
                }
            }
        };
        return picture;
    }

    **private void captureImageView(){
        //Visibitlity of camera photo
        cameraPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        capturedImageHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int screenHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Matrix mtx = new Matrix();


        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            // Notice that width and height are reversed
            Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, screenHeight, screenWidth, true);
            int w = scaled.getWidth();
            int h = scaled.getHeight();

            // Perform matrix rotations/mirrors depending on camera that took the photo
            if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
            {
                float[] mirrorY = { -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1};
                Matrix matrixMirrorY = new Matrix();
                matrixMirrorY.setValues(mirrorY);

                mtx.postConcat(matrixMirrorY);
            }

            // Setting post rotate to 90
            mtx.postRotate(270);
            // Rotating Bitmap
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaled, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
            //capturedImageHolder.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            capturedImageHolder.setImageBitmap(scaleDownBitmapImage(bitmap, 350, 450));
        }else{// LANDSCAPE MODE
            //No need to reverse width and height
            Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, screenWidth,screenHeight , true);
            bitmap=scaled;
            //capturedImageHolder.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            capturedImageHolder.setImageBitmap(scaleDownBitmapImage(bitmap, 650, 300));
        }
    }**

    private Bitmap scaleDownBitmapImage(Bitmap bitmap, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
        return resizedBitmap;
    }

    OnClickListener captrureListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Visibitlity of camera photo
            cameraPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            capturedImageHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            new Loading().execute();
            //timer.schedule(task, DELAY, DELAY);

            timerThread = new Thread()
            {
                public void run() {
                    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                image_animation.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);
                            }
                        });
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if(i==6){
                            timerThread.interrupt();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            timerThread.start();
        }
    };



    private final TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        private int counter = 0;

        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    image_animation.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);
                    i++;
                    if (i > imageArray.length - 1) {
                        i = 0;
                    }
                }
            });
            if (++counter == 6) {
                timer.cancel();
                timer.purge();
            }
        }
    };

    public class Loading extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            // 6000ms=6s at intervals of 1000ms=1s so that means it lasts 5 seconds
            new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    // every time 1 second passes
                    //tv.setText("" + millisUntilFinished/1000);
                   /* image_animation.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);
                    i++;
                    if (i > imageArray.length - 1) {
                        i = 0;
                    }*/
                }


                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    // count finished
                    //tv.setText("Picture Taken");
                    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, mPicture);
                }


            }.start();
        }
    }

    //make picture and save to a folder
    private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
        //make a new file directory inside the "sdcard" folder
        File mediaStorageDir = new File("/sdcard/", "JCG Camera");

        //if this "JCGCamera folder does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            //if you cannot make this folder return
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        //take the current timeStamp
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        //and make a media file:
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

        return mediaFile;
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        // stop and release camera
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    private void hideKeyboard() {
        View view = getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).
                    hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        // code here to show dialog
        super.onBackPressed();  // optional depending on your needs
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

What is the result I am getting right now  and what I want that is below. Please see during photo capture hand was in the right side but when photo preview is displaying it is showing in the left hand side.

So, what can be done to resolve the issue?

[image]

Comment: this happen only with front camera or back camera....?

Comment: @Omi   this is only for front camera, As I m using only front camera right now

Comment: Mirror display if front-camera preview is intentional and standard. Your users may be surprised or even upset to not have this feature that looks natural for them (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47497345). It is also widely expected to have captured picture or video without mirroring, as if taken by another person looking at you. Some apps, like snapchat, go extra mike to provide stills and recorded videos in mirror mode. As far as I can tell, most users accept this, but for some, it is frustrating (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47249032/192373).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately we can not disable mirror preview but we can use [TextureView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) and apply [SetTransform](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html#setTransform%28android.graphics.Matrix%29) to reverse Camera Preview, this work only with API >= 14 . so try below code in your PhotoCaputeActivity

```
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
matrix.postTranslate(width, 0);
mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
```

for more info check [this link.](https://github.com/hadders/camera-reverse)

Also keep in mind

> This is used with Front camera and when trying with Back camera make **mTextureView.setTransform(null);**

Answer (score 3):

At last I got solution by adding following attributes in the imageview and worked like a charm :)

android:scaleX="-1"

Answer (score 0):

in OpenCV JavaCameraView, it is very easy

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    imageMat = inputFrame.rgba().t();
    if (//horizontal reverse)
        Core.flip(imageMat, imageMat, 1);
    else //for vertical reverse
        Core.flip(imageMat, imageMat, -1);
```