# Recording camera not working after fix to ratio issues

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-camera

I'm very new to React Native and working at modifying an app that was built for me. I have fixed an issue with camera ratio looking squashed on the screen, however now I'm getting an unhandled promise rejection error. Previously, this would start recording:

```
const startRecording = async () => {
    setRecording(true);
    camera.current;
    const response = await camera.current.recordAsync(
```

However now it's saying `Undefined is not an object( evaluating 'camera.current.recordAsync' startRecording$)`

I assume it's because previously the camera was being defined as `const camera = useRef();` whereas the ratio fix [(from here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58634905/camera-preview-in-expo-is-distorted) is using `const [camera, setCamera] = useState(null);` but I'm not sure on how to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Probably quite basic, said I'm a noob!

useState() doesn't have the .current property. Removed that and it works.